# Audit tab in advanced security setting of printer does not appear in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security, printer

I want to audit printer access failures on Windows 7. But when I go to **printer properties->security->advanced**, there is not **Audit** tab there. If I try to audit folder, **Audit** tab is there, but for printer - no.
How can I make **Audit** tab appear for printer on Windows 7 or is there similar feature to audit printer access failures?

I tried to switch audit on in Security Policy, but that does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the auditing is enabled:

```
Double Click on My Computer, then double click Printers
Right click on the desired printer and select Properties
Click on the Security Tab
Select Auditing and click the Add button, you will be prompted with an Add Users and    Groups dialog box
Select the Users/Groups who you want to Audit for the Printer and click Add
Once finished click the OK button and in the Printer Auditing main dialog select the events to Audit, i.e. Print, Delete.
Print events will now be sent to the Security log which can be read from the Event Viewer   (Start - Programs - Administrative Tools).
```

If you experience problems with events not being audited try enabling File and Object Access as well.

Check this Technet [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976774.aspx):

If the tab is not visible, this means you do not have administrator permissions (Manage Printers, Manage Documents) for the server and you cannot continue.

At the bottom of this page:

For this procedure to work, the Audit Object Access option in Group Policy must be set to audit successful attempts, failed attempts, or both. To access this option, click Computer Configuration , Windows Settings , Security Settings , Local Policies , and then click Audit Policy .

Comment: Audit on files and folders does work. My user is in Administrators group, and I see 'Audit' tab in folder (or file) security properties. 'Audit' tab is absent only for printers.
I tried to change Audit Object  Access options in Group Policy, but nothing happens, 'Audit' tab does not appear.